# How to return chunks of vector from a function in c++

Tags: c++, function, vector, embedded, chunks

I would like to transfer data from one machine to other machine. Due to hardware & software limitations, the data i.e., vector(huge data) needs to be chunked and returned from my function which is implemented in C++. Could someone provide me a direction of **how the vector could be chunked and these chunks could be returned one at a time from that function?**
The fundamental problem here is, as the return function can only send first chunk and then obliviate, I am wondering how can I send all the chunks?

Comment: Use iterators to the vector?

Comment: I did, but how do I return all the iteration data from a function?

Comment: Either return a copy of the chunk (less efficient), or a pair of iterators to the beginning and end of the chunk.

Comment: std::ranges and/or std::span might be handy tools.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think std::span should work